# NSStringCompareOptions with NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;

Tags: ios, ios4, nsstring, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two strings

- String1 is from a file.
- String2 is in an `NSArray` (predefined list)

I want to compare the two strings and if it's a match, maybe do an `NSLog`

```
NSStringCompareOptions compareOptions = NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;
NSArray* countryIndex = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"alpha",
                                                         @"beta",
                                                         @"gamma",
                                                         nil];

for (NSString* element in countryIndex) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [(NSString *)country compare:element options:compareOptions];
}
```

So I'm very confused at what result is? (number, class, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Apple documentation available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).

If you do a search for 'NSComparisonResult' you will see it's an enum, containing constants you can use to check what the comparison operation resulted in.

Here's a brief snippet from the linked document:

```
NSComparisonResult
These constants are used to indicate how items in a request are ordered.

enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

So for instance, in order to use it in your code you could do the following:

```
NSStringCompareOptions  compareOptions = NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;
NSArray* countryIndex = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"alpha", @"beta", @"gamma' nil];

for (NSString* element in countryIndex) {
    NSInteger result = [(NSString *)country compare:element options:compareOptions];
    if(NSOrderedAscending == result) {
        // Do something here...
    }
    else if (NSOrderedSame == result) {
        // Do another thing here if they match...
    }
    else {
        // Try something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What does NSOrderedAscending mean??

Comment: I highly recommend you read Apple's documentation relating to comparison with NSString's [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-compare_options_).